# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException without the name of the class

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, classnotfoundexception, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I have a Unity game deployed to Android.

In Google play console, I am seeing many crashes that happen on old Android versions (<=7.1). The crash is caused by a ClassNotFoundException, but the report does not show the class that is not found.

In the crashes console I get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3025)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1565)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:179)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6152)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3020)
```

Which is too generic and does not hint on what class is missing.

I was wondering if there is another way to find the missing class. I am using Multidex (I don't know if it's relative to the problem).

Any help will be appreciated here..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found the cause for the ClassNotFoundException, which was not the multidex configuration, but a Receiver that one of my plugins added to the manifest with a class that was not included in the project.

More important is how I have found it, this can help others.. it appears that Google play console does not show the entire exception data if it's a multiline message. I have installed Firebase Crashlytics, and within a few hours got the actual missing class.

Here is what you get in Google play console:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3049)
```

Here is what you get in Firebase Crashlytics:

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Didn't find class "com.mintegral.msdk.click.AppReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bbumgames.spadesroyale-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.bbumgames.spadesroyale-1/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.bbumgames.spadesroyale-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.bbumgames.spadesroyale-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.bbumgames.spadesroyale-1/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

I am not sure why Google is not showing the second line, seems like a bug to me, but anyways, my problem is now solved.

Comment: I have **exactly** the same problem, having `ClassNotFoundException` without class name in Google Play Console. So, based on your success, I integrated Crashlytics. Let's see tomorrow my Firebase console...

Comment: @Zotyi did Firebase show you the class that was missing?

Comment: @qwiboo I think so, but I can go back only 90 days in the crash log of Firebase Console, so cannot check which one

Comment: @Zotyi I don't really care about the actual class. I just want to know if Firebase Crashlytics actually really shows you more info from the logs than just the logs in google play console?

Comment: @qwiboo: Yes, much more verbose

Comment: how did you do that? do you have to publish your app again? i am guessing you implemented into your app and made a new release?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a multiplex issue. 
In your build.gradle (module-level) add the following if not already there:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3’
}
```

If you don’t have an application class in your app add this to your manifest (within the application tag):

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

If you do, then add this:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
      @Override
      protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
         super.attachBaseContext(base);
         MultiDex.install(this);
      }
    }
```

[**Read more about it here**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: Multidex is enabled, but only by adding the multiDexEnabled flag and not doing the other steps.
I have read that if I target android versions greater than 20, this is the only steps needed (?). Maybe Unity does the rest.. https://appmediation.com/unity-enable-multidex/
Anyways, can Multidex be this exception's source?

Comment: @Ran your minSdkVersion needs to be higher than 20 in order for the above to be taken care of automatically, not your targetSdkVersion.

Comment: Ok, I will change my minSdkVersion. Not sure if this is the cause to the problem.. reading other posts it seems that the AndroidX library might be problematic